# is it possible to validate numeric key in laravel validation rules?

Tags: laravel, validation

i create my html form dynamically and my elements name are numeric. like:

```
<input name="1" id="1" class="form-control"/>
```

can I validate numeric key when I use In-built validator like:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
   $input=>'required|string|min:3|max:100'
]);
```

and in my case `$inpute = 1`?

its seem always fails or return this error:

```
{"message": "The given data was invalid.","errors":[["The 0 field is required."]]}
```

Comment: You want to validate `name` property, not the `value`?

Comment: how about you set them up as an array instead ... `name="something[]"` ... `'something.*' => 'required|....'`

Comment: You might just have a typo... Is it `$input` or `$inpute`? Does it work with `$inpute => 'required|string|min:3|max:100'`?

Comment: no, I want to validate the value but laravel validation doesn't accept numeric key

Comment: Because I make the elements dynamically, It is better to name them numerically

Comment: no, it's not typo, If I manually replace 1, there would be the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported in Laravel and has not yet been agreed to be added. ([Further Details](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/39368))

Answer (score 0):

You can patch your code to keep using dynamic numerical keys by prepending a fixed string to the keys.

On the HTML side do:

```html
<input name="k_1" id="1" class="form-control"/>
```

On the validation side do:

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate([
   "k_$input"=>'required|string|min:3|max:100'
]);
```